# How can we use token.json file in this google v1 api?

Tags: python

[forms/snippets/create_form.py](https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/29ae92ef31050764fd6d902b3b318f185a65166e/forms/snippets/create_form.py)

When I run this script it will go to authorization section and I authorization successful and a file create Name = token.json

Now error is this when I close my code and restart code then code not using this token.json file instead of this Python code go to 1 more time to authorization section and when I try next time it will go to authorization section.

Then how can I use this token.json file in this code

Comment: Access tokens are short lived. I assume a TTL of 1 hr. So after that time, it expires and goes for authentication

Comment: I try in 1 minutes gap not for 1 h wait

Comment: Another problem is , you / the snippet is not using the storage to store the token any where. So its quite obvious, after you reset your vm your creds are lost ?

Comment: Can you give me code to store my token file it will very helpful for me(i can manuplate code bot not create code)